# How to present ViewController using notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, controller, notifications

Here is the issue -
I have ViewController "A".
From it I need to present ViewController "B" when notification appears.

1. I subscribe to notification in viewDidLoad method of controller "A"
2. I make method to handle notifications.
3. In this method I try to present ViewController "B" like this -

   ```
   BViewController *bviewcon = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BView" bundle:    [NSBundle mainBundle]];
   UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:bviewcon];
   [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

What happened - view controller "B" appeared but with unpredictable delay - 2-10 sec.

If I tap on the screen view controller "B" load immediately.
If I put something in completion, for example NSLog - it also appears with same delay.

So can somebody help?

Comment: How are you generating your notifications?

Comment: Really I'm not sure that it connects with notifications..I just explain whole situation. I call it -                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOW" object:b];

Comment: in fact notification works fine. other methods in didRecivedNotification handle correct. Without any delays.